# Return last ID from a column

Tags: oracle, csv, talend

Is there a way to return the last ID from a column (called `ID_MES`) without browsing through all of the records?

My job Talentd:

[image: my job TALEND]

Comment: USING CAPS is considered screaming. You might want to [edit] your question. Since we cannot see inside your components, it is not possible to help. What is the column `ID_MES`? What do you want to use the last id for?

Comment: @Sami Meskaoui: I believe you should edit your question ,showing the schema of the tFileInputDelimited ,and also if the ID_MES column exists in the input file,is there any sorting criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without browsing the records it's not possible to find out the last records. However we can minimize the data flow between the components as follows.

For simplicity I am demonstrating the input as fixed flow input.
The logic is as follows.

1. Suppose there are 'N' number of columns for each record, then first we will consider the column we are interested in using 'tFilterColumns' and eliminate all other columns.
2. Find the last value of that column using tAggregateRow.
3. put the value in the globalMap [or] simply display the value using tJavaRow.

*Find the below job which i have developed.*

I have created a fixed flow with 6 columns and 12 records as shown in the image below.

[image]

I am interested in 'ID_MES' column alone, therefore i am using tFilterColumns. By using this component we can eliminate the unnecessary data flow.

[image]

***Then a tAggregateRow is used and in it's operation section of component properties, I used 'ID_MES' as output column with 'last' function.***

[image]
[image: This is the tJavaRow component where we can use the last 'ID' value]

And finally the output is as follows.

[image]

Comment: This works provided the author doesn't need the other fields or handles those with a separate flow. Nice solution.

Comment: Thank you very much